# how to have multiple text open different activity pages

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, textview, onclick

I'm creating an app for my work, an interactive guide.

In the app i have an FAQ page with a list of questions, i want to be able to have each bit of text open another activity page in the app when clicked. below is the XML code so far for my layout:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bgapp"
    tools:context=".faq">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="310dp"
        android:layout_height="86dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
        android:src="@drawable/bfcfulllogotransparent" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="79dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="160dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="530dp"
        android:src="@drawable/bfchandtransparent"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/homeicon"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/faq"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:text="Frequently Asked Questions"
        android:textColor="#ffff"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/faqnext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:text="Ive just gone into Foster Care, What happens next?"
        android:textColor="#ffff"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/faqfostercare"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="170dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:text="What is Foster Care?"
        android:textColor="#ffff"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/faqfamily"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="205dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:text="Will I still see my family?"
        android:textColor="#ffff"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/faqfriends"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="240dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:text="Can I still see my friends?"
        android:textColor="#ffff"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/faqsocialwork"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="275dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:text="What is a Social Worker?"
        android:textColor="#ffff"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/faqschool"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="310dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:text="Do I have to change school?"
        android:textColor="#ffff"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/faqovernight"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="345dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:text="Can I stay overnight at a friends?"
        android:textColor="#ffff"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/faqcourt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="380dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:text="What happens in court?"
        android:textColor="#ffff"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/faqadvocate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="415dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:text="What is an Advocate?"
        android:textColor="#ffff"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/faqguardian"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="450dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:text="What is an Guardian?"
        android:textColor="#ffff"
        android:textSize="20dp" />




</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is the Java (i've not touched the Java for this page yet:

```
package com.example.childrensguide;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class faq extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_faq);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can see this documentation https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity

or you can call the function like this:

```
TextView faqnext = findViewById(R.id.faqnext);

    faqnext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //use startActivity to next page
            Intent intent = new Intent(currentActivity.this, nextActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: maybe add the following to your code for a more comprehensive answer: Intent intent = new Intent(currentActivity.this, nextActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

Comment: @NikosHidalgo ok thanks I edited my answer